# Is there a way to record I/O file access and pipe it to a running process?

Tags: windows, sockets

On Windows, is it possible to create a specific file type that directly reads and writes data to a running process rather than from or to disk? On Linux this seems to be possible with socket, which are a special file used for inter-process communication. I have found a few documentations about this on Windows as well, but I am not sure how safe or common they still are in 2020.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: Windows has a "//./pipe/" filesystem for named-pipe files that support bidirectional IPC. They get created by [`CreateNamedPipe`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createnamedpipea). It has a "//./mailslot/" filesystem for mailslot files that support unidirectional IPC, including broadcast. They get created by [`CreateMailslot`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-createmailslota).

Comment: Windows 10 supports `AF_UNIX` `SOCK_STREAM` sockets that are named in a filesystem, but it's just a regular file that's associated with the socket in the kernel. It is not a reparse-point file, as claimed in [AF_UNIX comes to Windows](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/af_unix-comes-to-windows). Writing to the file itself has nothing to do with the socket.

Comment: Thanks, I would accept that as an answer!